# how to make count timer increase in hour, minute, seconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to make count timer from 00:00:00, the count start if "div id = data" is filled with "const date" and the time increase until the code receive stop trigger. how i can achieve that?

here is my current code :

```
<div id="data"></div>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const api_url = 'json.php'
async function okejson() {
            const resp = await fetch(api_url);
            const dat = await resp.json();
            const awal = (dat[0])
            const date = awal.tanggal
            document.getElementById("data").innerHtml = date

var distance = 0;
var x = setInterval(function() {
distance +=1;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  
}, 1000); }
</script>
```

Comment: Something should trigger the "Start Counting", when do you want the counter to start, on load? When you press a button?

Comment: I'm sorry Mr. Thomas, I forgot to insert the detail. I already edit my question. I want the count start when dev id= data is filled with date. please help me sir?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. Do you want
A. Counter to start counting from the moment "data" get a value like 00:00:01, 00:00:002 etc
B. Counter to count down from "now" to the date?
or something totally different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setInterval` will not yeild accurate results. It is acceptable for short periods and non critical applications. If it may take hours you should consider using system clock. However here is a constructor which you can use to generate an object which has a start (and also stop and reset) method on it. The start method accepts a callback function which it will call each second and passes an object with `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` properties. You can use it to do whatever you want.

```js
function Timer() {
 this.value = 0
 this.updateCb = null
 this.interval = null

 function getTime() {
   console.log(this.value)
   var seconds = this.value % 60
   var minutes = Math.floor(this.value / 60)
   var hours = Math.floor(this.value / 3600)
   var days = Math.floor(this.value / (3600 * 24))
   return { days: days, hours: hours % 24, minutes: minutes % 60, seconds }
 }

 this.start = function (cb) {
   if (cb) this.updateCb = cb
   clearInterval(this.interval)
   var self = this
   interval = setInterval(function () {
     self.value += 1
     if (self.updateCb) self.updateCb(getTime.bind(self)())
   }, 1000)
 }

 this.stop = function () {
   this.clearInterval(interval)
 }

 this.reset = function () {
   this.value = 0
   clearInterval(interval)
 }
}

var timer = new Timer()

timer.start(function (time) {
 console.log(time)
})
```

You can start the timer on click of a button or whatever other event.

Comment: thankyou so much Mr. Ahmad for your help :-)
i'm enlight your code is working amazingly :-)